# Is it possible to reverse the connection of a client connected to a Google Meeting?

Tags: reverse-shell

I was watching some videos of Jim Browning on Youtube and I have noticed that he reverses the connection of the scammer and gets remote access to their devices.

So I was wondering about the risks that one innocent person like me could run into by connecting to a google Meeting.

Is it possible that someone gets remote access to my device (Eg: Laptop) If I connect to their Google meeting?

Should I always use a Virtual Machine to connect to Meetings?

Comment: Virtual Machine?  Clearly you have not yet heard of a VM escape if you think that will save you.  The second question is unanswerable, I'd suggest dropping it.  Security is about threats.  If you are taking a meeting with someone who you believe has the skills to reverse the connection and enough ill intent to do it, precautions should be taken.  Or the meeting shouldn't.

Comment: OMG Never heard of VM escape but I will surely check it out. Thank you very much, and you are right I shouldn't join to the meeting but I was also checking and google does not connect client to client, its client to server and the server (Not like Omegle where you can even get the other person's IP address and probably try some attacks)

Comment: Paste the link here so one could possibly identify which method he used.